OData Code Generation for specific Client Version
for internal reasons I need to use Microsoft.Odata.Client in version 6.15.0.
When I try to generate the code to consume my V4 service (using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marketplace.ODataConnectedService2022), I get problems in the generated code, as it seems to be creating it for the latest version of the Nuget (7.21).
Is there any way to set the generator tool so that it works for my version of the library?
I have tried other version of the code generator (Unchase, VS 2019).
I have tried correcting manually the generated code, but I'm unable to. Also it doesn't seem like the best idea long term.
